# Comparing String with strncmp(s1, s2, n) in c programming

Tags: c

I was trying to understand how it operates, when I give a negative value of `n`, I expected that it should not give a proper answer and also  how will it compare and give output

Comment: N is an unsigned integral type, so the question is moot: n cannot be negative

Answer (score 2):

The last argument to `strncmp` is of type `size_t` which is an unsigned type. Therefore, it cannot be negative.

It would not make sense to give a negative number either. The last argument is *how many* characters that should be compared. You cannot compare -2 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that entering a negative number might technically be undefined behavior, which means that the compiler can do whatever it wants. Generally, though, if you enter a negative number, it will wrap around and you'll get a huge positive number instead. On my machine, `printf("%zu\n", -1);` prints `0xFFFFFFFF`. In this case, `strncmp` will compare up to the first 4,294,967,295 characters.

Comment: " negative number might technically be undefined behavior" --> the negative values is converted to `size-t`, likely a large value.  Not UB, but still a problem.

Comment: `printf("%zu\n", -1);` _is_ UB and certainly `printf("%zu\n", -1);` does _not_  print `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: I should have been more clear. My computer prints 4294967295, which is the decimal form of the hexadecimal number 0xFFFFFFFF. I meant to make it clear that we're wrapping around, so that -1 becomes 2³² − 1.

Comment: If you want to do this without UB, do `printf("%zu", (size_t) -1)` instead